# Using Regular Expression to extract value

Tags: c#, regex

Could someone please help me with this scenario,

```
[Some text]

[Some text] Device ID: XYZ123 [Some text]

[Some tex]
```

I want to extract `XYZ123` from the above sample. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the `[`, `]` of `[some text]` an actual character to be found in the text?

Comment: @Felix - no '[' and ']' wont be in the text. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(?<=Device ID: )\b[a-Z0-9]+\b
```

(get ID via catch group #0)

Assuming your regex engine supports lookbehinds, otherwise use:

```
Device ID: (\b[a-Z0-9]+\b)
```

(get ID via catch group #1)

Note: I herein assume that the `[` and `]` are not actually found in your source text, are they?

Comment: thanks. below code worked.

string expression = @"Device ID:(\b[a-z0-9]+\b)";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, expression,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
        string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);
}

How can i make sure that it works for both - Device ID: XYZ123 & Device ID:XYZ123

Comment: Device ID: ?(\b[a-z0-9]+\b) - I think this is what I need

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://regexr.com?2vgrm):

```
\[[^\]]+]\s*Device ID\:\s*(?<DeviceID>[A-Z0-9]+)\s*\[[^\[]+\]
```